# How to avoid setting hard-coded values to the point arguments of pspicture?

Tags: pstricks

I want to shrink and expand the canvas based on the 2 variables `\Base` and `\Angle`. The following code still use a hard-coded value for the ordinate of `pspicture`, which is equal to 6, for example.

I want to avoid using such a hard-coded value. I want to replace it by something that equals to `Angle tan Base mul`. Is there any idea to do so?

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\Base{3}
\def\Angle{60}

\pstVerb
{
    /Base \Base\space def
    /Angle \Angle\space def
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\Base,6)
    \pspolygon[fillcolor=yellow,fillstyle=solid](!Base 0)(!0 Angle tan Base mul)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick hack:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{fp}

\def\newconst#1#2{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \pstVerb{/#1 \csname#1\endcsname\space def}%
}


% User defined constants
\newconst{Base}{4}
\newconst{Angle}{30}
\newconst{Height}{Base*tan(Angle*pi/180)}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\Base,\Height)
    \pspolygon(!Base 0)(!0 Height)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see my edit, I used fp, but it is also possible without the fp package

Comment: that was only for testing, makes it easier to see if everthing works well